# ExtJS2.2 expand() Combo but dont focus it

Tags: extjs, extjs2

I'm working on an "old" application in ExtJS 2.2 and the method expand of Ext.form.ComboBox doesn't work in my case.

I just do

```
Ext.getCmp('adresse_field_ville').expand();
```

But nothing happends, even not a trace in console.

I'm sure to use the good object, because juste before I do

```
Ext.getCmp('adresse_field_ville').setValue('');
```

And it works.

By googling I found the method onTriggerClick. This method expands the combo and focuses it but i need to keep the focus on an other field.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try focus do the expanding, add focus event in the listener

listeners: {
  focus: function(fld) {
   this.onTriggerClick();
  }
}

Execute the focus event:
Ext.getCmp('adresse_field_ville').focus(false,100);